# Retrieving MySQL timestamp in python

Tags: python, mysql

My python code is running on a pi. I need to get the timestamp off the SERVER. 
Here is my code

```
cursor = cn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT current_timestamp()')
timestamp = cursor.fetchone()
testvar = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I get TypeError: Must be string, not tuple

Comment: `timestamp` -> `timestamp[0]`

Comment: `fetchone` returns a tuple. Just get the value out of the tuple

Comment: Also if using Sqlalchemy. There is a built-in function `scalar()` for the same.https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.scalar

Comment: Thanks. mad gave me the answer I needed. testvar = timestamp[0] then I can do x = 'time: ' + str(testvar)